# Change column name in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to change predefined column name to a new name.

```
eg: Column name is "Accounts"
I want to change it to "A/c"
```

alter table emp change Accounts....[What next]

Comment: What in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) do you not understand?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the sp_rename command, or use Management Studio to do it visually - make sure you do it at a quiet period, and make sure it has been done in pre-production first with testing!

Incidentally I would keep away from A/C - the slash sign is special meaning division.

The documentation for sp_rename is here, example B is most appropriate.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx

Comment: Where t1 is the table, and Accounts is the column, you would run this to change the column to Acc. Make sure you test it first in non-prod, and take a backup!

EXEC sp_rename 't1.Accounts', 'Acc', 'COLUMN';

Comment: What is this 'COLUMN' keyword used for at d end?

Comment: It's a parameter to the stored procedure (that command) that tells it to change the column name, rather than changing a table name for example.

Answer (score 20):

The script for renaming any column :

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```

(Note that you *don't* use escapes in the second argument, surprisingly.)

The script for renaming any object (table, sp etc) :

```
sp_RENAME '[OldTableName]' , 'NewTableName'
```

see [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/) for further info

Comment: is there no need for alter table statements?

Comment: @techie - Did you follow the link? What did it say?

Comment: yes i did see that link prior to posting here but its the first time i am working on SQL server environ so kinda confused abt things here

Comment: Actually -- and this surprised the heck out of me -- `sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'` gives the column the name `[NewColumnName]`, not `NewColumnName`. You don't use the `[]` escape in the second argument. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: If you do add the `[]`, see  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21169214/591097](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21169214/591097)

Answer (score 1):

```
sp_rename 'table_name.accounts', 'A/C', 'column'
```

this query will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sp_rename` as:

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

as your code is like this:

```
sp_RENAME 'table.Accounts','Acc','COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for sp_rename

```
sp_RENAME 'emp.Accounts' , 'Acc'
```

I used something similar and worked

Answer (score 0):

The command to rename any column name :

```
sp_RENAME 'TableName.[OldColumnName]' , 'NewColumnName'
```

It works without using the 3rd argument **'Column'** in the end.