# Rename object that has square brackets in the name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in one of my tables which has square brackets around it, `[Book_Category]`,  which I want to rename to `Book_Category`.

I tried the following query:

```
sp_rename 'BookPublisher.[[Book_Category]]', 'Book_Category', 'COLUMN'
```

but I got this error:

> Msg 15253, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 105 Syntax
> error parsing SQL identifier 'BookPublisher.[[Book_Category]]'.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: In general: When in doubt as to SQL syntax or escaping, do it in the GUI and click the options to make it generate a script.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You do it the same way you do to create it:

```
exec sp_rename 'BookPublisher."[Book_Category]"', 'Book_Category', 'COLUMN';
```

---

Here's a little sample I made to test if this was even possible. At first I just assumed it was a misunderstanding of how `[]` can be used in SQL Server, turns out I was wrong, it is possible - you have to use double quotes to outside of the brackets.

```
begin tran

create table [Foo] ("[i]" int);

exec sp_help 'Foo';

exec sp_rename 'Foo."[i]"', 'i', 'column ';

exec sp_help 'Foo';

rollback tran
```

Answer (score 6):

Double quotes are not required. You simply double up closing square brackets, like so:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'BookPublisher.[[Book_Category]]]', 'Book_Category', 'COLUMN';
```

You can find this out yourself using the `quotename` function:

```
SELECT QuoteName('[Book_Category]');
-- Result: [[Book_Category]]]
```

This incidentally works for creating columns, too:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Book (
   [[Book_Category]]] int -- "[Book_Category]"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got that error, and was wondering why. You can get this exact error if the column name you are changing from doesn't exist. Might as well doubly make sure if you still get that error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I was missing the table when renaming the index.

```
USE database ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_rename N'Schema.Table.old_INDEX', N'new_INDEX', N'INDEX';  
GO
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

this works for me:

```
exec sp_rename ‘[dbo].[TableName].[OldColumnName]’, ‘NewColumnName’
```

Comment: Of course it works. That was not the issue.